# HTML default URL param on page load

Tags: html, angularjs, redirect

Task:
When I load page `http://127.0.0.1:53132/pages/login.html` I want it by default become `http://127.0.0.1:53132/pages/login.html#/existinguser`. Maybe someone can tell me how to make that?

I using html, angularjs.

Tried:`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=#/existinguser" />` but it keeps refreshing page infinitely.

**ROUTE CONFIG**

```
    loginApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/existinguser', {
            templateUrl: '../../pages/loginForms/existingUserForm.html',
            controller: 'existingUserCtrlr'
        })
        .when('/newuser', {
            templateUrl: '../../pages/loginForms/newUserForm.html',
            controller: 'newUserCtrlr'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: Really not enough known about your angular app configuration. Are you using a router...if so which one? Where is app entry point?

Comment: yes I am using route. I beginner in all that, so I cannot tell you which, just downloaded libs from main angularjs site.

Comment: probably `ngRoute` then. Show your routing configuration

Comment: yes ngRoute, posted configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For default path use `otherwise` in routing config:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/existinguser', {
        templateUrl: '../../pages/loginForms/existingUserForm.html',
        controller: 'existingUserCtrlr'
    })
    .when('/newuser', {
        templateUrl: '../../pages/loginForms/newUserForm.html',
        controller: 'newUserCtrlr'
    }).otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/existinguser'    
    });
```

This means that if none of the defined routes exist in url when page loads, the path in the `redirectTo` will load

Comment: Thank you for fast help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the default route in the router with the 'otherwise' option

When you first navigate to your site you probably load the index.html. that needs to redirect to the #/whatever route you want and the router then takes over from there.

Technically with the # you are still on the index.html page and you whole app is a single page, with the router routing requests on the client, not the server, but loading the proper template in the Dom to show the page you want, loading it from the server if needed (if not cached previously)

Try this doc

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07